# Check if FORMAT is valid based on a pattern list

Tags: php

Using URLs..
I have a list of acceptable url formats, like this:

1. domain.com/test
2. domain.com/test/
3. domain.com/test/?test=1
4. domain.com/test/?test=1&bla=2

User input this `anydomain.com/any/?test=1` will return True based on my #3 entry at url format list..

The user input something like `anydomain.com/any/asd/?test=1`
return false.. `domain.com/` return false, because does not match with any entry of my format list.

whats the best way to do this?

edit: im not trying to check if url is valid! i'm trying to check if FORMAT is valid based on my pattern list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use regular expressions to do that:

```
$validFormats = Array(
    'domain.com/test',
    'domain.com/test/',
    'domain.com/test/?test=(\d+)',
    'domain.com/test/?test=(\d+)&bla=(\d+)'
);

$urlToCheck = 'domain.com/test/?test=1';

$isValid = false;
foreach($validFormats as $format) {
    if(preg_match('#^'.$format.'$#i', $urlToCheck)) {
        $isValid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($isValid) {
    echo 'Forbidden!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function of php for valid format of url

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
    return FALSE:
}
```

NOTE

Valid url start from `http://` OR `https://`

Comment: no... i need to check if url is valid based on formats of my list.

Comment: you can just append `http://` at starting and check with this function. Just create your url like `http://domain.com/test/?test=1&bla=2`

Comment: im not trying to check if url is valid! i'm trying to check if FORMAT is valid based on my format list..

Comment: yaa it will give you the result of valid url format not a valid url

Comment: ok, forget URLs.. i changed the title: Check if FORMAT is valid based on a format list
:)

Comment: check like this `<?php
$url="http://domain.com/test/";

 if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
       echo "1300003";
    }else{
echo "133";
}`

Comment: http://domain.com/ need to return false, because does not match with any entry of my format list.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a regex like this :

```
function checkUrl($var) {
    if(is_array($var) || is_object($var)) {
        return false;
    }
    return (preg_match("`^([a-z0-9]+)\.([a-z0-9]+){2,4}/([a-z0-9]+)/?(\?[a-z0-9A-Z&=]+)?$`", $var)) ? true : false;
}
checkUrl("anydomain.com"); // false
checkUrl("anydomain.com/any"); // true
checkUrl("anydomain.com/any/"); // true
checkUrl("anydomain.com/any/?test=1"); // true
checkUrl("anydomain.com/any/?test=1&bla=2"); // true
checkUrl("anydomain.com/any/asd/?test=1"); // false
```